# Pandas loop not producing enough rows

Tags: python, loops, pandas

I'm having trouble with an iterator not iterating. I'm trying to lookup each item of df1 in df2: the lookup row should correspond with the value of 'Start' in df1. I then want to return the column name of the match. E.g. for df1[2,0], it should look up row 'C' in df2, and return 'C', which is the column containing the matched value (5).

df1:

```
                 0        1        2        
0                1        3        6     
1                4        4        3     
2                5        6        2    
Start            C        A        B
```

df2:

```
                 A        B        C               
 A               6        3        4           
 B               2        3        6    
 C               4        1        5
```

So far, I've got:

```
for i, row in df1.iterrows():
    for ii in range(0,len(df1.columns)): 
        col = df1.columns[ii]          
        result = pd.DataFrame(df2.loc[df1.loc['Start']].eq(col).idxmin(1))
```

This gives me a series (C,B,C), where it's only done the matching for row 0 of df1. The ideal output is a 3x3 dataframe corresponding to df1 without the 'Start' row:

```
                 0        1        2        
0                C        B        C     
1                A        C        B     
2                ...
```

Any pointers greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the problem correctly the output you provided is incorrect. it should be:

```
  0 1 2
0 B B C
1 A C B
2 C A A
```

I am not very fluent at pandas but was able to get a version working..

```
def find_key_by_value(dic, value):
    for k, v in dic.items():
        if v == value:
            return k

data = {0:[], 1:[], 2: []}        
index = [0, 1, 2]       

for i, row in df1.iterrows():
    if i != 'Start': # Avoid calculating last line
        for ii in range(0,len(df1.columns)): 
            col = df1.columns[ii]

            to_match = row[ii] # number to match
            to_start = df1.loc['Start'][ii] # row under Start label

            # this is where my lack of pandas knowledge appears
            df2_row_keys = df2.loc[to_start].to_dict()
            result = find_key_by_value(df2_row_keys, to_match)
            data[ii].insert(i, result)

# data = {0: ['B', 'A', 'C'], 1: ['B', 'C', 'A'], 2: ['C', 'B', 'A']}
result = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=index)
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I would recommend is:

```
result = []
for y, row in df1.iterrows():
    if y == 'Start': # Skip the row named 'Start'
        continue
    result.append([]) # Make a new row in the result
    for x, item in row.iteritems():
        start = df1.loc['Start', x] # The same column, but in the start row
        search_row = df2.loc[start] # The row to look for a match in
        occurences = search_row.where(search_row == item)
        result[y].append(occurences.argmax()) # '.argmax' limits it to one occurence.
print(pd.DataFrame(result))
```

Which gives the output:

```
   0  1  2
0  B  B  C
1  A  C  B
2  C  A  A
```